# How do I delete a structure from a binary file?

Tags: c

How do I remove an employee from the binary file, after the user specifies which employee they want to delete by entering in there ID number? When the user enters the ID I want to remove all the information corresponding to that employee.

```
struct EmployeeInformation {
    char Firstname[32];
    char Lastname[32];
    char Address[32];
    char ID[8];
    char Duration[8];
};

struct EmployeeInformation Employee;

void DeleteEmployee() {

    FILE *fd;
    char EmployeeID[8];

    printf("\n>>Delete Employee<<\n");

    //Ask user for ID of employee they wish to delete.
    printf("Employee ID:");
    fgets(EmployeeID, 6, stdin);

    if ((fd = fopen(BINARY_FILE, "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error, Cannot Open File.\n");
    } else {
        fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&Employee, sizeof(struct EmployeeInformation), 1, fd);

        if (strcmp(EmployeeID, Employee.ID) == 0) {

            //Employee Found

        } else {
            printf("Employe Not Found!\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(fd);
}
```

Comment: You have two choices.  1 is rewrite the file without the record in question.  2 is to mark the record as deleted in some way (you'd need to account for this in other comparisons/searches etc.)

Comment: @Joe If I was to use a '*' at the first byte as the mark for a deleted employee. How do I write the '*' to the first byte of the employee I wish to delete.

Comment: @Joe is right, the best way is to mark your record as unused, and optionally clense the file of unused entries. The latter process can be done periodically.

Comment: @StephenFox Use "rb+" as mode.

Comment: @StephenFox Are really needed to use raw binary file to store regular data? The better choice is to use database. There is e.g. [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) database that has C language binding and stored data also in one binary file (no network, servers or anything similar required). You just need to figure out how to use this library (not more than dozen functions) and write simple SQL queries. Sqlite3 do all replacements, records delete and others by itself.

Answer (score 3):

The most common way to delete an entry from a file is to mark it as deleted by putting a flag in your structure with something like this:

```
struct EmployeeInformation {
    char Firstname[32];
    char Lastname[32];
    char Address[32];
    char ID[8];
    char Duration[8];
    int deleted; // deleted!=0 means record deleted
};
```

If you cannot modify the structure (maybe because you already have a written file) a solution could be: every time you need a delete operation, write the whole file in a new one, without write the deleted record.

Please, take note that if you have a file with a lot of record, a delete operation will cost you a lot of time (for rewrite all the records in the new file). So, i suggest you to use a flag to mark records as deleted and sometimes (maybe 1 time a week) rewrite the whoole file for removing the deleted records.

Comment: Normally you don't include extra fields for that. Just zeroing it should set more than one invalid/deleted flag.

Comment: @Deduplicator in this case you're right but sometime, for example when your struct has ints, 0 is a valid value, so you cannot distinguish between a valid struct and a deleted one

Comment: Actually, for validity you don't look at the C type, but the semantic type. Thus, record definitions without invalid values are vanishingly rare. (So my normally was an understatement)